# Search in Json and get limited search results

Tags: javascript, json

I've a JSON file which looks like this

```
[{
    "id": "2",
    "word": "Aam",
    "type": "n.",
    "descr": " A Dutch and German measure of liquids, varying in different cities, being at Amsterdam about 41 wine gallons, at Antwerp 36 1\/2, at Hamburg 38 1\/4.",
    "track": "a",
    "track_2": "Aa",
    "track_3": "Aam"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "word": "Aard-vark",
    "type": "n.",
    "descr": " An edentate mammal, of the genus Orycteropus, somewhat resembling a pig, common in some parts of Southern Africa. It burrows in the ground, and feeds entirely on ants, which it catches with its long, slimy tongue.",
    "track": "a",
    "track_2": "Aa",
    "track_3": "Aar"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "word": "Aard-wolf",
    "type": "n.",
    "descr": " A carnivorous quadruped (Proteles Lalandii), of South Africa, resembling the fox and hyena. See Proteles.",
    "track": "a",
    "track_2": "Aa",
    "track_3": "Aar"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "word": "Aaronic",
    "type": "a.",
    "descr": " Alt. of Aaronical",
    "track": "a",
    "track_2": "Aa",
    "track_3": "Aar"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "word": "Aaronical",
    "type": "a.",
    "descr": " Pertaining to Aaron, the first high priest of the Jews.",
    "track": "a",
    "track_2": "Aa",
    "track_3": "Aar"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "word": "Aarons rod",
    "type": "",
    "descr": " A rod with one serpent twined around it, thus differing from the caduceus of Mercury, which has two.",
    "track": "a",
    "track_2": "Aa",
    "track_3": "Aar"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "word": "Aarons rod",
    "type": "",
    "descr": " A plant with a tall flowering stem; esp. the great mullein, or hag-taper, and the golden-rod.",
    "track": "a",
    "track_2": "Aa",
    "track_3": "Aar"
}]
```

I want get first 2 or 3 result's by where word = "Aa" , track_2 = "aa" , track_3 = "aar" .. how can i do that ?

> What I need
>   1. Query in Json by String
>   2. Get Limited results 
>   3. I want to search in the json file by 2-3 conditions

i'm trying this

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchField = $('#search').val();

        $.getJSON('files/aa.json', function(data) {

            var jsonArrr = data;
            var matchMe = new RegExp('^' + searchField, 'i');
            var matches = [];

            for (var i in jsonArrr) {
                if (jsonArrr[i].word.search(matchMe) > -1) {
                    matches.push({
                        'id': jsonArrr[i].word,
                        'word': jsonArrr[i].word
                    });
                }
            }

            for (var i in matches) {
                console.log(matches[i].word);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a way to get what I need by expanding some code ?

Comment: Any reason you're not parsing the json into an object and just compare properties?

Comment: I think this line - `'id': jsonArrr[i].word` should be changed to `'id': jsonArrr[i].id`

Comment: I'm using json file as an offline database for firefoxOS that's why i'm parsing json into an object @Shilly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add few lines in this part -

```
var matches = [];

for (var i in jsonArrr) {

    if ( jsonArrr[i].word.search(matchMe) > -1 && jsonArrr[i].type.search(matchType) > -1 ) { // define matchType for the type keyword

            matches.push( {'id': jsonArrr[i].word , 'word': jsonArrr[i].word} );

    }

if(matches.length == 2) { // replace 2 with your number of results - 1
break;
}

}
```

Comment: it works! but I want to search in the json file by 2-3 conditions too .. any solution for that ?

Comment: 2-3 conditions more?? example?? you are searching for a string in the `word` property of every object, do you want to search for type,desc, etc also????

Comment: sorry for late reply  and yes .. i want to search using type and word at the same time  ... but i don't need the descr search ..

Comment: use the same thing - `if (jsonArrr[i].type.search(matchMe) > -1) { ... }`. Use it this way for AND criteria (match type AND word) - `if (jsonArrr[i].word.search(matchMe) > -1 && jsonArrr[i].type.search(matchMe) > -1) { .... }`